# How to solve problem with loading scripts in laravel project?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image][image]Here is How I call my scripts file in html page but it doesn't load jequry.js or some other scripts correctly

```
<script src="/js/admin/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->

<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/js/admin/adminlte.js"></script>
<script src="/js/admin/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="/js/admin/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="/js/admin/demo.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: your question need to more detail like error in console

Comment: Check if you are giving the correct path to your jquery.js and other files

Comment: in which folder is your html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in path `"/js/admin/jquery.js"` i not see a jquery.js file, pay attention that exactly your path must be ture, I think your jquery paht is `"/js/admin/jquery/jquery.js"`

Answer (score 0):

You Can do like that

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/adminlte.js') }}"></script>
```